# C++ object instance member function memory representation

Tags: c++, memory

How exactly are the member functions in C++ represented in memory? I understand that there are basically three types of functions:

-Static: These are represented as any other global function

-Virtual: These can be accessed through the vtable, during run-time, in order to perform dynamic dispatch.

-Non-static and Non-virtual: I am in trouble here. Most articles, or explanations say, that they are just represented the same way as normal functions are in the code, the only difference is they expect a hidden "this" pointer as an argument, to be able to access the data of the instance. However, I am not quite sure how is this represented/implemented. For example, if I have:

```
class A:
  int var_a;

  public:
   int get_member_var_a(){
    return var_a;
   }

   A(int init): var_a(init) {}

 A* instance_of_a = new A(4);
```

Now if I call

```
int tmp = instance_of_a->get_member_var_a();
```

Does the instance of the objet `A` have a pointer to the function `get_member_var_a` stored somewhere in the memory, and simply it calls the function, while passing an instance pointer as an extra argument?

Comment: go and give a try to python. After a few examples with classes (after the first actually) you'll see why I sent you there.

Comment: I am using python regularly ^^

Comment: that's what happens there: member functions in python are regular functions where the first parameter is the object itself (`__self__`). In C++, java, etc this mechanism is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second assumption is probably true for most of implementations.

`int A::get_member_var_a()` will most probably be compiled to something like 
`int __internal_compiler_prefix___A___get_member_var___thiscall(A* this)`

all `a->fun()` will be 'replaced' by compiler with `fun(a)`.

storing address to function inside instance is just too big overhead (couple of bytes per method per object) and as such is even probably prohibited by standard.

Answer (score 1):

The non-static non-virtual functions will be mangled into "new" functions by the C++ compiler. Also, the first parameter to the "new" functions will be the "this" pointer.

```
 instance_of_a->get_member_var_a();
```

The compiler will convert the above line to something like:

mangled_function_name_for_get_member_var_a(this)

For example, the compiler may mangle the function to something like _ZN1A16get_member_var_aEv.